# Python parse a string into n-depth dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string of keys separated by a delimiter `|` followed by  a value.

The string might be

```
key1|key2|key3=value
```

This should parse as

```
dct[key1][key2][key3] = value
```

The individual dictionaries might already exist.

To get the prototype started I have hard coded the creation of the dictionaries like this (fields is the main dictionary - already existing, s is the sequence of keys separated by `|` (pipe) :

```
   keys=s.split('|')     
   if len(keys) == 1:
        fields[keys[0]] = field_data
   elif len(keys) == 2:
        if keys[0] not in fields:
            fields[keys[0]] = {}
        fields[keys[0]][keys[1]] = field_data
```

I extended this for three-depth dictionary, but it is very inelegant I know.

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work?

Comment: Why can't it just be dct[key1 + key2 + key3] = value?

Comment: Lutz Horn: My question was how to expand this to n-depth dictionary at the same time make it more elegant.
Damian: This works but does not allow easy access to subsets (dct[key1] for example) and doesn't look as good in my yaml output when the dictionary is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
s = "key1|key2|key3=value"

keys, value = s.split('=')
keys = keys.split('|')

base = {}

reduce(
    lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}),
    keys[:-1],
    base
)[keys[-1]] = value

print base # {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
```

If you need this often, it might be worth making a class:

```
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, collections.Iterable) or isinstance(key, basestring):
            super(NestedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
            return
        keys = list(key)
        reduce(
            lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}),
            keys[:-1],
            self
        )[keys[-1]] = value
```

and then:

```
s = "key1|key2|key3=value"
keys, value = s.split('=')

base = NestedDict()

base[keys.split('|')] = value

print base # {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
```

Comment: Yes, excellent (I had to look up reduce - and in python 3 it is in functools). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a dictionary with three dimensions? Use a simple dictionary with tuples as keys:

```
s = "key1|key2|key3=value"
ks, v = s.split("=")
dct = {}
dct[ks] = v
```

Now you can access `dct` like this:

```
print(dct[("key1", "key2", "key3")])
```

Output:

```
value
```

Comment: This looks interesting - and would work for that value, but I don't think it allows for the individual dictionaries to be accessed - for example all the data in [key1]

Comment: Also, I save the dictionary in a yaml file and this approach loses the structure of the data - much less easy to read. But it is an approach I will use elsewhere, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will assume that your keys and values are strings. I.E:

```
key1|key2|key3=value
dct['key1']['key2']['key3'] = 'value'
# The literal strings
```

Then you can create a function that takes a string and splits it.

```
def str_as_key(string, dictionary=None):
    dictionary = dictionary or {}
    keys = string.split("|")
    keys[-1:] = keys[-1].split("=")
    value = keys.pop()
    dicti = [dictionary, []]
    for key in keys:
        dicti = [dicti[0].get(key), dicti[1] + [key]]
        if not isinstance(dicti[0], dict):
            exec("dictionary['{0}'] = {1}; dicti[0] = {1}".format("']['".join(dicti[1]), '{}'))
    exec("dictionary['{}'] = '{}'".format("']['".join(keys), value))
    return dictionary
```

The thing about this method is that it doesn't have to create a new dictionary. It can update one and leave other keys untouched. e.g:

```
>>> s = "key1|key2|key3=value"
>>> str_as_key(s, {})
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
>>> str_as_key(s, {"key1": {"key2": 12, "foo": "bar"}, "pi": 3.14})
{'pi': 3.14, 'key1': {'foo': 'bar', 'key2': {'key3': 'value'}}}
```